# Can anyone ID this torso? White torso with electronics and tubing printed

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

Looks to be a Star Wars pilot torso, but I tried many different keywords on BrickLink and could not find this torso!! I found many very similar torsos, but not this one. Would appreciate any help in finding this part ID, thanks!
[image: Torso Front]
[image: Torso Rear]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [973pb0270c02 Torso SW AT-AT Driver Pattern / Dark Bluish Gray Arms / White Hands](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0270c02&name=Torso%20SW%20AT-AT%20Driver%20Pattern%20/%20Dark%20Bluish%20Gray%20Arms%20/%20White%20Hands&category=%5BMinifig,%20Torso%20Assembly%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]

Comes from three possible sets: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0270c02&in=S

Comment: Thank you! That was what threw me off: I forgot that it could be a driver, not a pilot. Just needed the ID for inventorying it :) It was with a bunch of other minifig parts none of which seem to be very complete/with their sets.